# how to retrieve ATMs List from OSM

Tags: openstreetmap, java, osmosis

I am using this command to get the ATMs list

`osmosis --read-xml my_map.osm --tf accept-nodes amenity=atm --write-xml output-nodes.osm`

But it is giving the list of nodes and ways also...I want only nodes and is there any relation for these nodes and ways.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  Wherever possible it is best to spell out abbreviations the first time they are used in your Questions, and often to embed links to references.  I'm confident that OSM stands for OpenStreetMap but does ATM stand for Automatic Teller Machine or something else?  You can use the edit button beneath your Question to revise it with these details.

Comment: Talking of Openstreetmap, http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Atm should be the right adress.

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that you will miss information when leaving out areas and relations?

Comment: Dupe of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/147573/extract-amenity-from-pbf-file-using-osmosis

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want ways and relations, you can use either

```
--tf accept-nodes amenity=atm --tf reject-ways  --tf reject-relations
```

or use node-key-values:

```
--nkv amenity=atm
```

you should also look out for `atm=yes` (http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:atm%3Dyes) for cases where the machines are tagged on to the area of the building. So leaving out ways and relations might not be a perfect idea.